# What is the recommended way to customize the LogoutFilter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters, logout

I have a spring-based web-application, where I need the user to be logged out automatically, when certain conditions are met. I would like to have the same effect as if the user navigated to the `logout-url` configured in `<security:logout logout-url="url" success-handler-ref="handler" />`.

As far as I understand, this happens in the `LogoutFilter`, where all `LogoutHandlers` are called that are defined for this filter.

My idea was to create a subclass of `LogoutFilter`, so that I can implement my own logic in the `requiresLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` method:

```
public class CustomLogoutFilter extends LogoutFilter {

    public CustomLogoutFilter(LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler, LogoutHandler... handlers) {
        super(logoutSuccessHandler, handlers);
    }

    public CustomLogoutFilter(String logoutSuccessUrl, LogoutHandler... handlers) {
        super(logoutSuccessUrl, handlers);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean requiresLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        boolean result = super.requiresLogout(request, response);
        result &= isCustomCondition();

        return result;
    }

    private boolean isCustomCondition(){
        // evaluate custom condition and return the value
    }
}
```

I tried declaring `CustomLogoutFilter` as a bean with `LogoutFilter` as its parent, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Is it possible to configure `CustomLogoutFilter` in a way that it's used by the web-app instead of the standard `LogoutFilter`? Is there a recommended way of implementing this logic?

I'm using spring-security v. 3.2.5.

Comment: Do you think it would be enough to implement a custom [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's a possible solution. Is it possible to configure Spring so that the `LogoutFilter` uses my `customLogoutRequestMatcher` instead of the default `logoutRequestMatcher` that's defined in the filter-class?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java configuration instead of [Security Namespace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-namespace) (XML) configuration, you could write your own [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) and add them to the [`LogoutFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.html), see [`LogoutConfigurer#logoutRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutRequestMatcher(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher)):

> The RequestMatcher that triggers log out to occur. In most circumstances users will use `logoutUrl(String)` which helps enforce good practices.